# cassandra java client throws string index out of range exception

Tags: java, database, exception, cassandra, cql

I am getting following exception when running a query from Cassandra cql java client.

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1949)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraResultSet.createColumn(CassandraResultSet.java:1159)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraResultSet.populateMetaData(CassandraResultSet.java:220)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraResultSet.<init>(CassandraResultSet.java:190)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:169)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.executeQuery(CassandraStatement.java:229)
at com.jolbox.bonecp.StatementHandle.executeQuery(StatementHandle.java:503)
at com.wyh.cluster.node.connect.JDBCConnect.query(JDBCConnect.java:77)
at com.wyh.service.TripWorker.runRouteQuery(TripWorker.java:3557)
at com.wyh.service.TripWorker.getRouteInfo(TripWorker.java:3495)
at com.wyh.service.TripWorker.run(TripWorker.java:607)
at org.jppf.server.node.NodeTaskWrapper.run(NodeTaskWrapper.java:136)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

When I look at CassandraResultSet.java:1159 here
http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/source/browse/src/main/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql/jdbc/CassandraResultSet.java?spec=svn3be43d719cf12d92d067c20b3d1c23682c25a304&r=61cefd982fd281f80fbb6485754c8f7831193114

It seems more of a bug to me. The cql query which is being generated in the code is working in the cqlsh client. Any workaround for this.

*UPDATE*

I am now moved to datastax driver where I am using these jar files.
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/reference/settingUpJavaProgEnv_r.html

Now, whenever I am trying to obtain the session I am getting this exception. Surprise to the fact that the method is there in the class.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureTask.create(Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFutureTask;
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.newTaskFor(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:46)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.newTaskFor(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:131)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:58)
at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.addOrRenewPool(SessionManager.java:247)
at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.init(SessionManager.java:66)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:199)
```

Comment: Why you are not using datastax java driver?

Comment: Query is quite simple 
"SELECT * from <table> where id=1"

This is a little old project and i was using this driver from the beginning and it was working fine with cassandra 1.2. I have not explored datastax java driver. can you tell me which jar files to download.

Comment: You shall get the package in their site downloads section

Comment: The issue was due to a timestamp column in my table. I think that's a bug in the driver. I removed that column in my query since I am not using that column and was able to get rid of the issue but certainly that's not a workaround.

Comment: @Ananth Please see the updated issue

Comment: Yes. It's clearly a bug in the driver.

Comment: @Ananth did you get a chance to look at the issue I am facing now. I have updated the question.

Comment: Yes. Saw the exception. Thats why i had answered its a bug in the affirmative.